# How can I use pandas dataframe to_dict with float32 without additional float decimals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to use `dtype='float32'` (it is probably a numpy dtype => `np.float32`) instead of `dtype='float64'` to reduce memory usage of my pandas dataframe, because I have to handle hugh pandas dataframes.

At one point, I'd like to extract a python list with `'.to_dict(orient='records')'` in order to get a dictionary for each row.

In this case, I will get additional decimal places, which are probably based on s.th like this:

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/9620269)

How can I cast the date / change the type etc. in order to get the same result, as I get with `float64` (see example snippets)?

```py
import pandas as pd

_data = {'col1': [1.45123, 1.64123], 'col2': [0.1, 0.2]}

_test = pd.DataFrame(_data).astype(dtype='float64')

print(f"{_test=}")
print(f"{_test.round(1)=}")
print(f"{_test.to_dict(orient='records')=}")
print(f"{_test.round(1).to_dict(orient='records')=}")
```

`float64` output:

```
_test=      col1  col2
0  1.45123   0.1
1  1.64123   0.2
_test.round(1)=   col1  col2
0   1.5   0.1
1   1.6   0.2
_test.to_dict(orient='records')=[{'col1': 1.45123, 'col2': 0.1}, {'col1': 1.64123, 'col2': 0.2}]
_test.round(1).to_dict(orient='records')=[{'col1': 1.5, 'col2': 0.1}, {'col1': 1.6, 'col2': 0.2}]
```

```py
import pandas as pd

_data = {'col1': [1.45123, 1.64123], 'col2': [0.1, 0.2]}

_test = pd.DataFrame(_data).astype(dtype='float32')

print(f"{_test=}")
print(f"{_test.round(1)=}")
print(f"{_test.to_dict(orient='records')=}")
print(f"{_test.round(1).to_dict(orient='records')=}")
```

`float32` output:

```
_test=      col1  col2
0  1.45123   0.1
1  1.64123   0.2
_test.round(1)=   col1  col2
0   1.5   0.1
1   1.6   0.2
_test.to_dict(orient='records')=[{'col1': 1.4512300491333008, 'col2': 0.10000000149011612}, {'col1': 1.6412299871444702, 'col2': 0.20000000298023224}]
_test.round(1).to_dict(orient='records')=[{'col1': 1.5, 'col2': 0.10000000149011612}, {'col1': 1.600000023841858, 'col2': 0.20000000298023224}]
```

Comment: `float32` and `float64` are `numpy` constructs, and by extension `pandas`.  Double check this, but I bet your `dict` contains Python floats, which are essentially `float64`.  Without examining the dataframe in detail, my guess is that conversion to `dict` will increase the memory use, regardless of the dataframe `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj I've also tried to create a numpy array with type `float32` with one decimal place but nothing change. 
Can you explain your idea?

Comment: A float that displays as `12.3` does not take up any less memory than a `12.3000234`. - 4 or 8 bytes depending on dtype.  When converted to a string the extra decimals do make a difference.  But we don't use strings to save memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing float representation has [some limitation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)
for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838431/mitigating-floating-point-approximation-issues-with-numpy)

Using to_dict() function switch from numpy representation to python native float representation, this means a sort of translation. Nevertheless the precision you are using, some small pieces of information will be lost.

For a no-lossy convertion you must cast your number to string **before** the *to_dict()* using the *as_type()* function:

```py
_data = {'col1': [1.45123, 1.64123], 'col2': [0.1, 0.2]}
_test = pd.DataFrame(_data).astype(dtype='float32')
_test.round(1).astype('str').to_dict(orient='records')
```

```
_test.round(1).astype('str').to_dict(orient='records')=[{'col1': '1.5', 'col2': '0.1'}, {'col1': '1.6', 'col2': '0.2'}]
```

An alternative can be the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) format.